# Vertical Tab doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I create a vertical tab but it doesn't work. I can't found where is the problem.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="sidemenu">
  <li>
    <a href="#home-content" class="open"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i><strong>Home</strong></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#about-content"><i class="icon-info-sign icon-large"></i><strong>About</strong></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#ideas-content"><i class="icon-lightbulb icon-large"></i><strong>Ideas</strong></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#contact-content"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i><strong>Contact</strong></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <div id="home-content" class="contentblock">
      <h1>The Main Page!</h1>
      <p>I swear this has some really great stuff. Content is courtesy of <a href="http://bluthipsum.com/">Bluth Ipsum</a>.</p>

      <p>Smack of ham. What is she doing at a beauty pageant? Is she running the lights or something? She's always got to wedge herself in the middle of us so that she can control everything. Yeah. Mom's awesome.</p>

      <p>Probably out there without a flipper, swimming around in a circle, freaking out his whole family.</p>

      <p>Fun and failure both start out the same way.</p>
    </div><!-- @end #home-content -->


    <div id="about-content" class="contentblock hidden">
      ...
    </div><!-- @end #about-content -->

    <div id="ideas-content" class="contentblock hidden">
      ...
    </div><!-- @end #ideas-content -->

    <div id="contact-content" class="contentblock hidden">
      ...
    </div><!-- @end #contact-content -->
</div><!-- @end #content -->
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantora+One');

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
body { 
  font-size: 62.5%; 
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 45px 20px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #fff url('../images/bg.png'); /* http://subtlepatterns.com/connected/ */
}

br { display: block; line-height: 1.6em; } 
img { border: 0; max-width: 100%; }

h1 {
  font-family: 'Cantora One', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.0em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #787878;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  color: #575757;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a { color: #8dadd8; }
a:hover { color: #7299cf; }

/* main page */
#w {
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: none;
}


#content {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  min-height: 300px;
}


.contentblock {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.contentblock.hidden {
  display: none;
}
/* side navigation */
#sidemenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border-right: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}


#sidemenu li { display: block; text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #fff; font-size: 1.1em; }

#sidemenu li a { 
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 2px;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1;

}
#sidemenu li a:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

#sidemenu li a strong { 
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#sidemenu li a.open {
  width: 101%;
  background: #fff;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function(){
  $('#sidemenu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      // do nothing because the link is already open
    } else {
      var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');
      var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');

      $(oldcontent).fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(newcontent).fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
        $(oldcontent).addClass('hidden');
      });


      $('#sidemenu a').removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is when click on tabs the content of that tab doesn't show and just the url is change.

This is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/395aabpk/).

Comment: connect the library jquery - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/cr2cydms/

Answer (score 1):

After I added jQuery library to your jsFiddle, it worked perfectly

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/395aabpk/4/)

```
code
```